# How to join_with multiple delimiters by ranges in C++?

Tags: c++, string, std-ranges, range-v3, c++23

Since C++23(or use range-v3 library), we can join a range of ranges with a delimiter like:

```cpp
std::vector<std::string> v{ "This", "is", "it" };
std::string result = v | std::views::join_with(' ') | std::ranges::to<std::string>();
// result is "This is it".
```

But what if I need a delimiter string instead of a delimiter character, e.g. double spaces? How can I do so by ranges?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`view::join_with` *already* accepts a range as a delimiter, so change it:

```
std::vector<std::string> v{ "This", "is", "it" };
auto result = v | std::views::join_with(std::string("     "))
                | std::ranges::to<std::string>();
```

It should be noted that after [P2281](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2281r1.html), range adaptor objects hold decayed arguments *by value*, so you *cannot* use the raw string literal `" "` as a delimiter because it decays to a `const char*`, which is not a range.

Comment: Err..... Sorry for that, I didn't try to add `std::string` before, so I got a compile error and thought it was impossible; but why is `"  "` wrong while `std::string("  ")` is OK? Why isn't there a conversion?

Comment: Get it, but when I try `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` joined with a `std::initializer_list<int>`, it still reports an error(but `std::vector<int>` is OK). Why? You can see an example on [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/q71xhdPzn).

Comment: @o_oTurtle In this case, you can call `views::join_with(v, k)` [instead](https://godbolt.org/z/8MM6Ma7Yq), because `v | views::join_with(k)` will copy `initializer_list` and forward it as an rvalue, which cannot be converted to `view`.